# Generating sample xml from XSD file using eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

I have searched the forum and i found few solution but not what i was looking for.

I have an XSD file(A.XSD) which imports 2 other xsd (B.XSD and C.XSD). When i try to generate sample xml from exlipse for A.XSD, i get "No rrot element exists since the schema provided has no global element".
But one of the imported xsd (B.XSD) has global element. How should i go about this, please help

Answer (score 0):

Try generating the XML for B.XSD and choose the rootElement (if you have more than one global element definitions) using which the XML has to be generated.

If B.XSD is not importing the A.XSD, what's the use of A.XSD which doesn't have any rootElement but uses B.XSD?

Comment: An example is to provide a concrete complex type in A.xsd, which extends an abstract type in B.xsd, the latter being used as the type of an element defined in B.xsd or C.xsd. Think xsi:type here.